# How to auto generate Retina and Non-retina images from psd

Tags: photoshop

I have a PSD file for my App Interface that was designed for Retina iPhones with a resolution of 640 x 1136. I want to add support for non-retina devices and and add all image assets with both a retina and non-retina version. I find the process of resizing every ui component on photoshop individually very tedious. Does anyone know how I can auto-generate Non-Retina images from the Retina images I have already exported? Thanks

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. This more of a general software question about generating different PNG files from a PSD file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Photoshop CC, you can use [Adobe Generator](http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshopdotcom/2013/09/introducing-adobe-generator-for-photoshop-cc.html) (especially nice when paired with Russell Brown’s free [Layer Namer extension](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2013/11/russell-browns-new-layer-namer-for-photoshop.html)). Adobe Generator automatically exports any layers whose names end with `.png`, and can also export multiple resolutions.

There are also some great posts on this topic by Marc Edwards on the [Bjango blog](http://bjango.com/articles/); specifically: [Exporting from Photoshop](http://bjango.com/articles/exporting/). His articles deal with creating a slice sheet that you export semi-automatically with scripts.

I have used both of these workflows in production. Each has its quirks, but they can both probably be made to do what you’re after.

A tip: I prefer to design at 1x and then scale up. If you design and scale down, you might make an asset an odd number of pixels wide, which could look bad when scaled down. But many graphic designers I've worked with prefer to design at 2x.

Answer (score 1):

For images i am using [Resizer](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/resizer/id411277085?mt=12) .Quite nice and fast application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to work from the original .psd then the free [SuperExport](https://github.com/bendytree/Photoshop-Scripts) Photoshop script might be of use.  It allows you to export flattened crops (not just entire layers) at multiple resolutions by careful naming of groups and layers.  Documentation is [here](https://github.com/bendytree/Photoshop-Scripts/blob/master/Super%20Export.md), and an updated version that also supports 3x is [here](https://github.com/robinmacharg/Photoshop-Scripts) (I'm the author of the - small - 3x modification).

The benefits, as pointed out in the docs, of using the original .psd are that you can see your design in context while selectively (and easily) regenerating assets with a single click.